# What's the meaning of "equals" in Java?

Tags: java

I know the source of "equals" method in Object class is below:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
return (this == obj);
}
```

Here is an example:

```
package equals;

public class Main {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Object ObjA = new String("BBB");
    Object ObjB = new String("BBB");
    System.out.println(ObjA.equals(ObjB)); //the result is:true
    System.out.println(ObjA == ObjB);      //the result is:false
}
}
```

I know it's true if I change

```
Object ObjA = new String("BBB");
Object ObjB = new String("BBB");
```

to

```
String strA = new String("BBB");
String strB = new String("BBB");
```

But now ,I use Object,I can't understand it.
Who can tell me the reason? 
Ths!

Comment: Here it doesn't matter what `Object`'s implementation of `equals()` is. Your objects are of type `String`. It's `String`'s implementation that matters.

Comment: equals() method matches two object and return true or false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is polymorphism of java. You can refer to following url for more information. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Also I wrote a simple program for your interest:

```
public class testPolymophism {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        animal a = new dog();
        animal b = new cat();
        a.call();
        b.call();
    }
}

class animal{

    public void call(){
        System.out.println("Specific to what animal is.");
    }
}

class dog extends animal{
    public void call(){
        System.out.println("Bark!");
    }
}
class cat extends animal {
    public void call(){
        System.out.println("Mia~");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Bark!
Mia~
```

Comment: I haven't a good understanding of  polymorphism of java.Thanks.I know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Java chooses method implementations at runtime (run-time dispatch), not when the code is compiled.  It does not matter that you told the Compiler to pretend that the String is of type `java.lang.Object`.  When the code is executed the method dispacther will choose the implementation of `equals()` from the true runtime type of the object.

Answer (score 0):

In java when you say:

```
ObjA == ObjB
```

It is interpreted absolutely pedantically as "Does Obja refer to the same object as Objb"

Whereas the ".equals" method is implemented within the object and varies from class to class. Mostly it does what you expect, i.e. compare some internal members of the class for equality. But it entirely depends on the implementation of the class.